# change text of UILabel with timer

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

i want to change the text of a UILabel after a certain amount of time. but the text isn't changed after the set amount of time. how do i fix this?

see my code:

```
var countDownText = "hello"

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

startButton = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 90))
    startButton.text = "\(countDownText)"
    startButton.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height/2)
    startButton.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    startButton.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
    startButton.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view?.addSubview(startButton)

countDownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDownFunc"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func countDownFunc(){
        theTime++

        if(theTime >= 4){
            countDownText = "testText"
        }

        if(theTime >= 8){
            spawnEnemys()
            startButton.removeFromSuperview()
            countDownTimer.invalidate()
        }
        print(theTime)

    }
```

thanks in advance for all your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `countDownFunc` should be:

```
func countDownFunc(){
    theTime++

    if(theTime >= 4){
        countDownText = "testText"
        startButton.text = countDownText
    }

    if(theTime >= 8){
        spawnEnemys()
        startButton.removeFromSuperview()
        countDownTimer.invalidate()
    }
    print(theTime)

}
```

Comment: sorry i didnt put the nstimer in my code sample but it is there exaclty how u suggested but it still doesnt change my text

Comment: where u put it? and where u call `countFuncDown`?

Comment: it is underneath the self.view.addSubview(startButton)

Comment: can u add it to your question? i want to see your code

Comment: is your `theTime` more than 4?

Comment: your log is just: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`?

Comment: oh, it is not a label. it is just a string. if u add `print(countDownText)` after `countDownText = "testText"` it will show that `countDownText` is changed

Comment: yes you are correct so how do i make the text in the UILabel change

Comment: how did u add a label?

Comment: what do you mean by label?

Comment: didn't work :( But i gtg for i sec ill be back in like a hour or 2 thank you for all your help so far!

Answer (score 2):

There's a design flaw in your code.

You change the string assigned to the view controller's `countDownText` property, but that does not also change the label's current text.

Here's a simple playground example to illustrate the problem:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

var label = UILabel()
label.text = str
str = "Goodbye, playground"

print(label.text) // "Hello, playground"
```

If you also want to update the label's text, you need to update its text property, similar to what you initially did:

```
startButton.text = "\(countDownText)"
```

This will update the label's text to match the `countDownText` property's new value.